# How to write function that accepts comparator in C?

Tags: c

I have a struct `vector` that holds it's data in a double void pointer. The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct vector {
    void **data;
    int capacity;
    int size;
} vector;
```

I am trying to somewhat replicate the `std::find` function in C++ to find items in the `vector` that I have. I have done this by creating a function `vector_find`:

```
int vector_find(vector* v, void *elem, __compar_fn_t cmp)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v->size - 1; i++)
    {
        if(cmp(v->data[i], elem) == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This function is found in my `vector.c` file. It accepts a comparator function. If it finds the element, it will return its location in the vector.

This is all defined in my `vector.c` file.

Now I am trying to use this function in one of my programs, in this function:

```
int cstring_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *ia = *(const char **)a;
    const char *ib = *(const char **)b;
    printf("%s    %s", ia, ib);
    return strcmp(ia, ib);
}

void
execute(vector* tokens)
{
    if (vector_find(tokens, ";", cstring_cmp) > -1)
    {
        printf("semicolon found");
    }
}
```

However, when I run this function, I get a segfault with the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S:120
120 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S: No such file or directory.
```

A couple of things I have verified:

1. I have verified that the error occurs in my `execute` function. Specifically when I call vector_find.
2. I have verified that this error comes up *whether or not* `tokens` is empty. This is interesting because the for-loop in `vector_find` should never execute if the vector I pass to `vector_find` is empty.
3. I have included  in both `vector.c` and the file I am running.

I have also tried this format:

```
int vector_find(vector* v, void *elem, int (*cmp) (const void*, const void*))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v->size; i++)
    {
        if((*cmp) (v->data[i], elem) == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

...and got the same error.

Am I doing this right? Obviously not - where does my error lie?

Comment: The `-1` certainly should be removed from `for (int i = 0; i < v->size - 1; i++)`

Comment: @chux Thank you, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison function is expecting that each of its parameters is a `char **`.  However, you call `vector_find` with a `char *` being passed as the second parameter which is subsequently passed to `cmp`.  Attempting to use a `char *` as a `char **` invokes undefined behavior as you end up passing to `strcmp` is actually a `char`.

You don't show how you populate your `vector`, but I'm guessing the elements of `data` are of type `char *`.  That being the case, the comparison function should be expecting a `char *` instead of a `char **`.

```
int cstring_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *ia = a;
    const char *ib = b;
    printf("%s    %s", ia, ib);
    return strcmp(ia, ib);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. You are completely right. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, you've written a comparator that pretends a `vector` is a `const char*`. It isn't. The subsequent C-string comparison is likely not to hit a would-be null terminator and is going to go out of bounds.

Instead, write a comparator that actually compares `vector` objects to whatever it is that you want to compare them to.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain to me why my comparator consumes `vector`? I am passing to it `v->data[i]` which, to the best of my knowledge, is a `void*`. Which is what my comparator expects.